# Storing user details in session but without login him yet in Laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

Is it possible when user type his login username and password to  store his details and redirect him to another page where I will query database for addition information which he provide before to log him? Consider this scenario:

1. User enter username/password
2. If they are correct store this user information and redirect to another page ( not logged yet )
3. Query database for addition information about this user

This is what I have so far

```
public function login() {
    return View::make('site.users.login');
} 

public function loginSubmit() {

    $validatorRules = array(
        'username' => 'required|alpha_dash',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    );

    Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validatorRules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    $user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    if (!Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $user->password)) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    Session::put('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]);
    return Redirect::to('/users/auth/' . $user->user_id . '?_token=' . csrf_token())->with('message_success', '.');
}

public function loginAuth() {
    Session::get('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]);
    $key = DB::table('users')->select('key')->where('user_id', '=', $data->user_id)->first();
    return View::make('site.users.auth', [
        'key' => $key
    ]);
}
```

Or there is another way to do this? This portion of source gave simple error

```
production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: user'
```

On session get function

```
Session::get('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your code like this:

```
public function loginAuth()
{
    $data = Session::get('user');
    $key = DB::table('users')->select('key')->where('user_id', '=', $data->user_id)->first();

    return View::make('site.users.auth', [
        'key' => $key
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect!